# Run mongodb query in a loop

Tags: mongodb

I have a user collection with IDs. I would like to run this query for all of them

```
db.user.updateMany(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(USER_ID)
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "player_ids": db.player.find(
                {
                    "author._id": ObjectId(USER_ID)
                }
            ).toArray().map(function(u) {
                return u._id;
             })
        }
    })
```

the script runs correctly for hardcoded USER_ID. I would like to run it for all IDs automatically.

Comment: You have a mix of `update` and `find` syntax here.  So you want to go through the `user` collection and for each user, lookup all the matching `id` in the `player` collection and set `player_ids` to that array i.e. `player_ids: [ id1, id2, id3 ]`   ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I intend to do here

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use `$lookup` in the `set` pipeline.  You will have to do it in a 2-step loop:

```
db.user.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var ids = [];
    db.player.find({"author._id": doc['user']}).forEach(function(d2) {
                        ids.push(d2['_id']);
            });
    db.user.update({"_id": doc['_id']}, {$set: {"player_ids":ids}});
    });
```